# Azure WebApp - Get Private IP of a service connected on VNET

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I have a Azure WebApp inside the VPN. When I go on networking I see the connection like this:

[image]

When I click on "Click here to configure"it appears to be up & running:

[image]

So, everything appears OK.

The VPN externally connects BUT where can I find the Internal "VPN" IP Address of this Web App?

If I go on configurations / SCM etc I can only find the "external" IP!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a normal App Service then you can't get it's IP, mainly because the application is running on a distributed environment and the exact location of the instance might change with little notice.

If you need a dedicated public (or private) IP, then I recommend you have a look at [Azure App Service Enviroments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro).

Comment: I created an Azure App Service Environment v2, added to my virtual network, create an App service Plan and a Web App in it. Now where can I find the private IP of my web app? Or, how can I configure it? Thanks

Comment: What's your use case, why do you need to know the private IP address?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue thins hours. My app service contains a rest service I want to access. Using ASE is not an option because my subscription does not support (I was suprised there are levels in scubscription AND app plans)

Comment: @evilSnobu the private IP address is needed in an ASE environment in order for a private DNS zone most typically, or if you need to add entries to your HOSTS file on a jumpbox on the vnet. Without this IP, you can't access private app services for example, since they need a HTTP host header to be sent by the browser. Without DNS or hosts entries, this is dead in the water. -- so, to find the private IP address with an ASE, look on the "custom domains" page. You need the IP to make A records. Without an ASE, the public IP is there instead. Service Endpoints will force traffic over VNET.

Comment: Understanding the private IP address can change, it'd be nice if the _current_ private IP address were shown somewhere. This would assist in troubleshooting (e.g. vnet is connected to on-premise network).